# How to keep/restore stderr after `tput smcup`

Tags: bash, tput

Given the following contrived example which intent is to only erase the subcommand's `/dev/tty`:

```bsh
result="$(
  tput smcup > /dev/tty
  tput cup 0 0 > /dev/tty
  echo 'meh' > /dev/tty
  echo 'nay' > /dev/stderr
  echo 'yay' > /dev/stdout
  tput rmcup > /dev/tty
)"; echo "result=[$result]"
```

It outputs:

```
result=[yay]
```

However, the stderr of `nay` is no longer kept in the display. How can I make sure that stderr is kept displayed? Such that the output is:

```
nay
result=[yay]
```

The real use case is where the subcommand asks the user a series of questions and calculates a response that is sent to stdout, and if an error occurs the error is sent to stderr. Once the subcommand is completed the intent is for the question interaction to be wiped, the stdout to be stored, and any stderr to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If you write to *stderr* the value isn't captured into the variable. This behaviour is by design. If you want to keep `nay` either you need to write it to *stdout* or you need to reopen *stderr* as *stdout* (which is much the same thing).

For the purpose of reducing confusion, this behaviour has nothing to do with `tput smcup` or any other terminfo characteristic.

Furthermore, the only value placed into `$result` will be the output written to *stdout*. Every other output will be written immediately to the terminal. The segment could have been far more straightforwardly written like this:

```
result='yay'

tput smcup
tput cup 0 0
echo 'meh'
echo 'nay'
tput rmcup

echo "result=[$result]"
```